# My infopanel screenlet is blinking all the time

Tags: 11.04, screenlets, widgets

Installed screenlets and infopanel but it is blinking all the time. Is somebody had the same problem and know how to fix it?

Comment: What exactly is blinking? A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: By 'blinking', do you mean flickering, like in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/screenlets/+bug/717989)?

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue  is addressed [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1358545) . The given fix is to

> check the  **~username/.config/Screenlets/InfoPanel/default**
>   where you have the .ini for the
>   infopanel. If there are two files,
>   delete the newest and log out and login.